# Use Promise.all instead of async/await if a forEach

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, discord.js

I am making a discord bot using `discord.js` which gets data from an API and add or delete the message associated with the data.

In the snippet below I have written the logic to delete the messages if the corresponding data is no longer available at API.

`gameEmbeds` is a map which contains `key` as the identifier for the data from API and `val` as the identifier for the message in the discord channel.

```
  gameEmbeds.forEach(async (val, key, map) => {
  if (map !== undefined && newGames.get(key) === undefined) {
    const message = await channel.fetchMessage(val);
    message.delete()
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`${new Date()} `, e);
      });
  }
```

I have to make iterator function `async` because every entry to be processed one by one to make the changes in the UI look smoother which violates the async nature of JS.

I think I can make sure this happens with `Promise.all` which will also make this code a bit faster, however, I don't know how to implement it in my code without breaking stuff. I am new to node.js. Please help.

EDIT: Thanks CF256, I removed redundant `.then()`

Comment: When using async/await you don't use .then or .catch. If fetchMessage is a promise that returns message, you can do const message = await channel.fetchMessage(val)

Comment: Thanks I want to optimize my code as much as possible. But how can I use `Promise.all` on `forEach`?

Comment: @CF256 How does it look now?

Comment: Do you realize that `.forEach()` does NOT wait for an async callback.  You are NOT serializing your operations here.  All the async/await is doing here is letting you call `message.delete()` after `channel.fetchMessage()` finishes.  Your loop is not serialized though.  All your operations are happening in parallel.

Comment: I want them to happen in parallel to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will create a new array for holding all the small promises, and once the `forEach` loop is complete, I will then call the `Promise.all` on the small promises keeper

```js
const allDeleteJobs = [];
gameEmbeds.forEach(async (val, key, map) => {
  if (map !== undefined && newGames.get(key) === undefined) {
    const message = await channel.fetchMessage(val);
    // Push the new delete job to the array registry
    allDeleteJobs.push(message.delete());
  }
});
(async () => {
  if(allDeleteJobs.length >= 1){
    await Promise.all(allDeleteJobs);
    // Delete all the messages or do other stuff
  }
})()
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: How can I push a function(`message.delete()`) in an array?

Comment: `Array.push(stuff)`

Comment: But `message.delete()` is a function, not a value, right?

Comment: Yes `message.delete()` is indeed a function, but you can still push it into an array, it won't break your code, and if somehow you want to retrieve the return value of the `message.delete()`, you can always get the value from the `Promise.all` function, and return format will be an array ordered by how you push the value before

Comment: Wait, I still didn't get rid of async/await in my function

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't get rid of `async/await`, but you already improve the performance by using only one `async/await`

Comment: I added `.then` on `channel.fetchMessage()` don't know if that will make any difference

Comment: I don't think it will break your code, but this will definitely make your code look more unreadable